# CSS animation (flutter effect)

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to implement flutter effect animation. I tried this

https://jsfiddle.net/rdLwnrhw/4/

Reference : https://jsfiddle.net/kcbnw1Lx/3/

```
<div class="post photo">
  <div class="col1">
    <img src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TC100x100S100x100~sample_galleries/2195357421/9191930200.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <img src="https://pim-resources.coleparmer.com/item/s/arcis-ufl002b-sample-prep-kit-50-reactions-1320452.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col3">
    <img src="https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TC100x100S100x100~sample_galleries/8541266682/9841279488.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
    <div class="col4">
      <img src="http://www.whosampled.com/static/user_images/r167890_201669_83041246780.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
    </div>
    <span class="folded-corner"></span>
  </div>
```

Here, in this example it is folding top right corner on hover. But I want to fold right bottom div for every second with out hovering.

Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `setInterval` method to toggle a separate `class` which adds and removes the effect from the post `div`.

You can see a working example below.

```js
var isOpened = false;
setInterval(function() {
  if (isOpened) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("folded-corner")[0].className = "folded-corner";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("folded-corner")[0].className = "folded-corner open";
  }
  isOpened = !isOpened;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.photo {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  border: dashed #004990;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4 {
  display: inline;
}

.post {
  margin: 0px 0px 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4), 0 0 40px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1) inset;
}

.photo {
  padding: 0px!important;
}

.folded-corner {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 0px #fff, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  -webkit-transition: border-width 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-width 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: border-width 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-width 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: border-width 0.2s ease-out;
}

.open {
  border-width: 0 40px 40px 0;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="post photo">
  <div class="col1">
    <img src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TC100x100S100x100~sample_galleries/2195357421/9191930200.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <img src="https://pim-resources.coleparmer.com/item/s/arcis-ufl002b-sample-prep-kit-50-reactions-1320452.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col3">
    <img src="https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TC100x100S100x100~sample_galleries/8541266682/9841279488.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
    <div class="col4">
      <img src="http://www.whosampled.com/static/user_images/r167890_201669_83041246780.jpg" class="lowes_logo" alt="Lowe's Home Improvement Logo">
    </div>
    <span class="folded-corner"></span>
  </div>
```